# C++ explicit char/short?

Tags: c++

I'd like to pass a char to my function (fn). I DO NOT want ints and shorts to be typecast into it. So i figure i should have the value be implicitly cast into MyInt (which will only support char) then pass into fn. This should work bc IIRC only one typcast is allowed when passing onto function (so char->MyInt is ok while int->char->MyInt shouldn't).

However it appears both int and char work so i figure another layer of indirection (MyInt2) would fix it. Now they both can not be passed into fn... Is there a way where i can have chars passed in but not int?

```
#include <cstdio>
struct MyInt2{
    int v;
    MyInt2(char vv){v=vv;}
    MyInt2(){}
};
struct MyInt{
    MyInt2 v;
    MyInt(MyInt2 vv){v=vv;}
};
void fn(MyInt a){
    printf("%d", a.v);
}
int main() {
    fn(1);       //should cause error
    fn((char)2); //should NOT cause error
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for compile or run time error?

Answer (score 11):

[Function templates to the rescue](http://ideone.com/TLw7F):

```
template<typename T> void fn(T t);

void fn (char a){
    printf("%c", a);
}
```

If someone attempts to call `fn` with anything other than a `char` argument the function template will be chosen as a match and the linker will complain that it cannot find the appropriate specialization.

Comment: Great answer as well. I cant pick between you two : X

Comment: lol +1. That could be his you know. If lets say I have 2 functions or 3 functions that require this ;)

Comment: Gah! [Function templates specialisations are evil](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)!

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: No they are not (how on earth do you reach this conclusion from Sutter's writeup?!?). They can be misused, which is the point Sutter wants to make, but in this case a template is a perfectly appropriate solution because there will not be any other specialization going on (partial or not).

Comment: @Jon: obviously it was an humorous exagerration, but Suter makes clear point that you can avoid problems by preferring overloads over specialisations (Important Morals and Summary). In this particular example, overload version is *shorter*, for one thing. It also helps avoid problems *upfront*. Really, what's the advantage of using specialisation here?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: The advantage is that a non-template would not work because it would allow implicit conversions to be considered (e.g. `int` to `char`). This is exactly what we want to avoid. In effect the template tells the compiler "there's a different specialized version of this function for each type of argument", but then we don't give the specialization for any type other than `char`. Hence you will never be able to call `fn` with a non-`char` argument because the compiler will not attempt to apply conversions.

Comment: @Jon: that's exactly the same what you'd achieve with an overload. Please, [have a look](http://ideone.com/Makty). Less code, less possible complications. Again, any advantages of choosing specialisation?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: Sorry, I misunderstood your intent. In hindsight it's obvious that you were not objecting to the template but rather the specialization. I have edited the answer to match your suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

You can use polymorphism and define several versions one accepting `int` and one `short` and throw exceptions or cause assertion failures, or hide the constructor:

```
struct MyInt2{
    int v;
    MyInt2(char vv){v=vv;}
    MyInt2(short s) { throw "short"; } /* exception, runtime error */
    MyInt2(){}
    private:
    MyInt2(int v) { } /* hidden, compile time error */
};
```

Comment: Beautiful. I knew C++ could handle this!

Comment: Jon answer is as great as this. I cant pick between you two : X

Answer (score 4):

You want `char` to implicitly convert into `MyInt2` which then to `MyInt`. But two level of conversion is not allowed by the language specification.

If you want to do it for one-level of *implicit* conversion, then C++11 can help you.

In C++11, you can `delete` constructor taking `int`, allow the one which takes `char` as:

```
struct MyInt{
    int v;

    MyInt(char vv) : v(vv) {} //use mem-initialization list

    MyInt(int) = delete;  //VALID only in C++11
};
```

Notice the *deleted* constructor which takes `int`, it means this:

```
MyInt m1(10); //error - can't accept int!

MyInt m2((char)10); //okay - can accept char!
```

See [Online Demo](http://ideone.com/8OYfj)

In fact, you can `delete` ALL constructors except one which takes `char` as:

```
struct MyInt{
    //..
    MyInt(char vv); //ALLOW
 
    template<typename T>
    MyInt(T) = delete;  //DELETED the rest!
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/OykxF)

Learn more about :

- [Explicitly deleted special member functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I hate to say this but really you could have easily put a comment in perreal answer saying "Alternatively you may use `MyInt(int) = delete;` in C++11 instead of making it private". +1 anyways

Comment: @acidzombie24: Why should I make it a comment, when it seems to be an answer for many readers who may wish to do something similar? Comments are less valuable, as not everyone reads them. And my answer contains good information.