# C# compile time error if Int?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, msbuild

I'm trying to [recreate this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11430449/34537) in C#.

The problem i get is if i use constructors i MUST use new MyInt which i DO NOT WANT (to verbose). The way around it is to use the implicit/explicit operators. However they MUST be public... How the heck do i implement this in feature in C#?

The short question is i'd like to pass byte/short into a function but not int. Passing int should get me a compile error. I know i can easily get runtime with a public implicit int operator. The code below shows that int is automatically converted to char

[Running sample](http://ideone.com/xPzU2) shows true

```
using System;
class Program
{
        public static void Write(MyInt v)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", v.v is byte);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Write(2);
        }
}
public struct MyInt
{
        public object v;
        public MyInt(byte vv) { v = vv; }
        public MyInt(short vv) { v = vv; }
        public MyInt(byte[] vv) { v = vv; }
        public static implicit operator MyInt(byte vv) { return new MyInt { v = vv }; }
        //public static extern implicit operator MyInt(int vv);
}
```

Heres [more code which is useless](http://pastebin.com/btyH1FJJ). It implements MyInt2/MyInt which isn't required in the C++ solution

Answer (score 3):

Just declare that your function takes short. Byte would be implicitly converted to short, but there is no implicit conversion from int to short, so int just won't pass

```
public class Class1
{
  public static void Aaa(short a)
  {

  }

  public void Bbb()
  {
    int i = 5;
    byte b = 1;
    short c = 1;
    Class1.Aaa(i); // Gives error
    Class1.Aaa(b); // Ok
    Class1.Aaa(c);  // ok
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, weird. Unfortunately Aaa(1) still works. Hmmm, i'll post another question. Ok done http://stackoverflow.com/q/11432508/34537