# Why can I pass 1 as a short, but not the int variable i?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, int, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Why does the first and second Write work but not the last? Is there a way I can allow all 3 of them and detect if it was 1, (int)1 or i passed in? And really why is one allowed but the last? The second being allowed but not the last really blows my mind.

[Demo to show compile error](http://ideone.com/tQjCm)

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Write(short v) { }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write(1);//ok
        Write((int)1);//ok
        int i=1;
        Write(i);//error!?
    }
}
```

Comment: I too am stumped by this, i often have to cast ints to short in function calls although they should be castable...

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin they are castable, that's why you can cast them. But it's a lossfull conversion (there are many ints that don't fit in a short), so implicit cast is not possible, that's why you have to write `(short) i`.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The first two are constant expressions, the last one isn't.

The C# specification allows an implicit conversion from int to short for constants, but not for other expressions. This is a reasonable rule, since for constants the compiler can ensure that the value fits into the target type, but it can't for normal expressions.

This rule is in line with the guideline that implicit conversions should be lossless.

> **6.1.8 Implicit constant expression conversions**
>
> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following conversions:
>
> - A *constant-expression* (§7.18) of type `int` can be converted to type `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the *constant-expression* is within the range of the destination type.
> - A *constant-expression* of type `long` can be converted to type `ulong`, provided the value of the *constant-expression* is not negative.

(Quoted from C# Language Specification Version 3.0)

Answer (score 67):

There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `short` because of the possibility of truncation. However, a *constant expression* can be treated as being of the target type *by the compiler*.

`1`? Not a problem: it’s clearly a valid `short` value. `i`? Not so much – it could be some value > `short.MaxValue` for instance, and the compiler cannot check that in the general case.

Comment: So... it does not matter how explicit i am... >_<. Do you have any idea if i can detect if a litereal was passed or a int variable?

Comment: @acidzombie24 You cannot. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: @acidzombie24 I don’t think you can detect that. You *can* however use a template argument and then use reflection to get at its type.

Comment: @acidzombie24 There is no way a literal could to be passed in during runtime. So you can just use your eyes to check at compile time.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Sometimes I want functions to only take explicit int types (say i am writing to a file and used 1 instead of (byte)1).

Comment: @acidzombie24 Unfortunately the cast operators are going to stop you there. I could create a `public static implicit operator int(FooContainingNonInts f)` and you'd not be able to stop me! Mwuahhahhahhaa! But in all seriousness, what would you gain from being able to stop that?

Comment: FooContainingNonInts isn't a literal ;) which is what i want to check. In my case i wouldnt mind FooContainingNonInts bc its hardly an accident if the return type is int vs short

Comment: @KonradRudolph template argument. Hmm, i think you're saying i can check via runtime but not compile time :(

Comment: @acidzombie24 In that case, would it be an option to accept the argument as an `Expression<Func<int>>`? Then you could pass `() => 1` or `() => i` and inside the function you could inspect whether the passed entity contained a captured variable or a constant value.

Comment: [There you go.](http://ideone.com/QR50g) (Note, this is still at runtime, not compile time; also, note that expression arguments are treated still differently). Sorry it took so long – had to do it in MonoDevelop without IntelliSense. :-/ Forget the upvotes.

Comment: Your answer is slightly wrong. You shouldn't use *literal* but *constant-expression*. In particular the second example is not a *literal*.

Answer (score 8):

an `int` *literal* can be implicitly converted to [`short`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Whereas:

> You cannot implicitly convert nonliteral numeric types of larger storage size to **short**

So, the first two work because the implicit conversion of literals is allowed.

Comment: Your answer is slightly wrong. You shouldn't use *literal* but *constant-expression*. In particular the second example is not a *literal*.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is because you are passing in a literal/constant in the first two, but there is not automatic type conversion when passing in an integer in the third.

Edit: Someone beat me to it!

Answer (score 4):

The compiler has *told* you why the code fails:

```
cannot convert `int' expression to type `short'
```

So here's the question you should be asking: why does this conversion fail? I googled "c# convert int short" and ended up on the MS C# page for the `short` keyword:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4(v=vs.71).aspx

As this page says, implicit casts from a bigger data type to `short` are only allowed for literals. The compiler can tell when a literal is out of range, but not otherwise, so it needs reassurance that you've avoided an out-of-range error in your program logic. That reassurance is provided by a cast.

```
Write((short)i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because there will not be any **implicit** conversion between *Nonliteral* type to larger sized short.

*Implicit conversion is only possible for constant-expression.*

```
public static void Write(short v) { }
```

Where as you are passing `integer` value as an argument to `short`

```
int i=1;
Write(i);  //Which is Nonliteral here
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting from int -> short might result in data truncation. Thats why.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from short --> int happens implicitly but int -> short will throw compile error bcoz it might result in data truncation.