# 0x80000000 == 2147483648 in C# but not in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, hex

In C#:

```
0x80000000==2147483648 //outputs True
```

In VB.NET:

```
&H80000000=2147483648 'outputs False
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is related to the history behind the languages.

C# always supported unsigned integers.  The value you use are too large for *int* so the compiler picks the next type that can correctly represent the value.  Which is *uint* for both.

VB.NET didn't acquire unsigned integer support until version 8 (.NET 2.0).  So traditionally, the compiler was forced to pick Long as the type for the 2147483648 literal.  The rule was however different for the hexadecimal literal, it traditionally supported specifying the bit pattern of a negative value (see section 2.4.2 in the language spec).  So &H80000000 is a literal of type Integer with the value -2147483648 and 2147483648 is a Long.  Thus the mismatch.

If you think VB.NET is a quirky language then I'd invite you to [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16459680/17034) :)

Answer (score 6):

The VB version should be:

```
&H80000000L=2147483648
```

Without the 'long' specifier ('L'), VB will try to interpret &H8000000 as an integer.  If you force it to consider this as a long type, then you'll get the same result.
&H80000000UI will also work - actually this is the type (UInt32) that C# regards the literal as.

Comment: but the problem is that VB literals are *signed* whereas in C# it's unsigned.  I believe that's the precise reason for the disconnect.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler do this automatically?

Comment: C# and VB have different approaches.

Comment: @KirkWoll: In this case the C# literal is unsigned, but that's not true generally for hex literals in C#.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the type of the hexadecimal number is `UInt32` in C# and `Int32` in VB.NET.
The binary representation of the hexadecimal number is:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Both `UInt32` and `Int32` take 32 bits, but because `Int32` is signed, the first bit is considered a sign to indicate whether the number is negative or not: `0` for positive, `1` for negative. To convert a negative binary number to decimal, do this:

1. Invert the bits. You get `01111111111111111111111111111111`.
2. Convert this to decimal. You get `2147483647`.
3. Add 1 to this number. You get `2147483648`.
4. Make this negative. You get `-2147483648`, which is equal to `&H80000000` in VB.NET.