# Why assigning an int literal to a byte variable is legal?

Tags: c#, .net

Assigning an `int` literal to a `byte` variable is legal:

```
byte b = 123;   // legal
```

However, assigning an `int` variable to a `byte` variable is illegal:

```
int i = 123;
byte b = i;     // illegal
```

Comment: Similar question: [Why can I pass 1 as a short, but not the int variable i?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432508/why-can-i-pass-1-as-a-short-but-not-the-int-variable-i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you assign a literal(constant value) compiler can prove the value fits in byte. When you assign a variable it can't.

If you assign a constant compiler is more than happy to compile because it can confirm that value is within the range of (0 - 255) which is the valid range for `byte`.

For example the following code compiles without any problem.

```
const int i = 123;
byte b = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

**The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28580485/14868997) is not quite correct.**

In the second example, of course the compiler *could* prove that the value will fit, using simple static analysis. It's not *allowed* to, by the language specification.

It's trivial for a compiler such as the IL Jitter to prove this, and it does on many occasions. The C# compiler cannot accept this because it is against the specification.

The example given in that answer, is allowed *because the spec allows it*, not just because there is proof.

```cs
const int i = 123;
byte b = i;
```

---

**Let's take a look at the spec, [ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf) section §11.2.10** (you may find [`microsoft.com`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-constant-expression-conversions) easier to navigate)

> **11.2.10 Implicit constant expression conversions**
>
> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following conversions:
>
> - A *constant-expression*(§12.20) of type `int` can be converted to type `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the *constant-expression* is within the range of the destination type.

Let's [take a look at §12.20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#constant-expressions) at what a *constant-expression* is defined as:

> **Constant expressions**
>
> A *constant_expression* is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.
>
> A constant expression must be the `null` literal or a value with one of the following types: `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, `object`, `string`, or any enumeration type. Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:
>
> - Literals (including the `null` literal).
> - References to `const` members of class and struct types.
> - References to members of enumeration types.
> - References to `const` parameters or local variables
> - Parenthesized sub-expressions, which are themselves constant expressions.
> - Cast expressions, provided the target type is one of the types listed above.
> - `checked` and `unchecked` expressions
> - Default value expressions
> - Nameof expressions
> - The predefined `+`, `-`, `!`, and `~` unary operators.
> - The predefined `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `&&`, `||`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` binary operators, provided each operand is of a type listed above.
> - The `?:` conditional operator.

**So, going back to the first example in the quesiton**

```cs
byte b = 123;
```

The value `123` is a literal integer, which is a *constant expression*, and fits a `byte` therefore it can be implicitly converted into `byte`.

Next,

```cs
int i = 123;
byte b = i;
```

Here the value `i` is *not* a *constant expression*, therefore it *cannot* be implicitly converted to `byte`. There is no way for the compiler to allow this, because the spec disallows it.

**Finally the example in the other answer**

```cs
const int i = 123;
byte b = i;
```

Here, `i` is a *constant expression* (because it is a reference to a `const`), whose value is known to fit into a `byte`, hence it is allowed *by the spec*.

Comment: `In the second example, of course the compiler could prove that the value will fit, using simple static analysis.` It also can't because of debuggers. Nothing stops you fiddling with the value in the debugger. So the status quo makes sense, in that regard.

Comment: True, but in optimized Release build you might have thought it would do so. Do you think I have analyzed it correctly, generally? I know this is an old post, but it got duped recently

Comment: `True, but in optimized Release build you might have thought it would do so.` I don't think the Release build will give different warnings to the Debug build - although I could be wrong. Do I agree with the answer _overall_? Yes, I do.